# SQL Exception A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

This is the problem I am having:

> Exception occurred
>   epos\SQLPlaygroundV1\SchoolDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

SQL script to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [FirstName] NCHAR(16) NULL, 
    [LastName] NCHAR(16) NULL, 
    [Age] NCHAR(3) NULL, 
    [DateOfBirth] DATE NULL, 
    [Enrolled] BIT NULL
)
```

C# used to write to database:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Admin-PC\\source\repos\\SQLPlaygroundV1\\SchoolDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True")) {
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand()) {
        command.Connection = connection;            
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT into Student (FirstName, LastName, Age, DateOfBirth, Enrolled)" +
                            " VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Age, @DateOfBirth, @Enrolled)";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "Bob");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", "Bobson");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", "21");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", "1990-01-01");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enrolled", false);

        try {
            connection.Open();
            int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(recordsAffected);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        } finally {
            connection.Close();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I've verified that no other file exists with the same name, the connection string is copied and pasted from the server explorer properties window.

I can see that it exists and that it is in the right path etc, I don't understand why it isn't finding it/ unable to access it.

Comment: "\\source\repos\\" one of these things is not like the others... :) You'll laugh when you see it.

Comment: Wow. Thanks @DanWilson... that fixed it I can't believe I missed that...

Comment: I nearly always use string literals (`@"file\path"`) to avoid this.

Comment: That's another solid point I'll definitely be using those from now on if you put those 2 points in an answer I'll mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the connection query, the path to the database, before `repos` you only have one backslash `\` you need to add another one.